# Does SharePoint have to be internet facing when connecting to dynamics-crm Online

Tags: dynamics-crm

Hi I'm trying to find some information at to weather SharePoint 2010 installed on prem needs to be available over the internet to integrate with dynamics-crm online
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well basically you need to have access to Dynamics CRM Online or it's webservices, so you need to have internet access.

But what you can do is develop a small integration platform as a console application that can access both your sharepoint farm and Dynamics CRM Online

Comment: Thanks, maybe i could be a little more clearer. Communication  from SharePoint to CRM should be fine as we have internet connection on prem however SharePoint does not have any public facing urls, its intranet only. My understanding is that to access SharePoint documents from within CRM online, CRM needs to have some connectivity to SharePoint be it via internet. Is it possible to not expose on SharePoint intranet over the internet and implement some bridge connection from CRM to SharePoint?

Comment: Okay, so you are talking about the opposite direction. I would say that that fact does not change my answer. You will still need to create some form of integrations layer